# How to get Windows AD Token in Spring Boot?

Tags: windows, active-directory, azure-active-directory, token

How can I get Windows AD Token in Spring Boot?
Because I want to check whether there is AD Token in the browser cookie, if there is AD Token in cookie, I could send the AD Token to AD Server to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you? F12 in chrome, and I can see all the session/cookie of the website.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I mean how to get AD token in Spring Boot code? I have no ideas how to get the AD Token, thanks.